# Omitting a verb in a clause starting in "sondern"

Tags: usage

Recently, I came across this German quote online:

> Nicht die Schönheit bestimmt, wen wir lieben, sondern die Liebe bestimmt, wen wir schön finden.

I also found another version which **excluded** *bestimmt* in the clause with 'sondern', i.e.

> Nicht die Schönheit bestimmt, wen wir lieben, sondern die Liebe, wen wir schön finden.

May I ask if the use of *sondern* allows for the **omission** of the verb *bestimmt*, which would also mean that *bestimmt* is implied as a follow-up from the first clause because of *sondern*?

Answer (score 5):

That has nothing to do with *sondern* specifically. You could put any conjunction there, and it would be valid. For example:

> Nicht die Schönheit bestimmt, wen wir lieben, **aber** die Liebe, wen wir schön finden.

This is called an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) and is quite common in many languages. As long as you can deduce which word is missing, you can omit the word.

There are a handful of conditions that have to be fulfilled, though. It's impossible to give you a full list of these conditions, because it highly depends on the context. Your example certainly requests a conjunction. Without a conjunction it doesn't really work.

> *Nicht die Schönheit bestimmt, wen wir lieben. Die Liebe, wen wir schön finden.

But I don't want you to believe that conjunctions are necessary in general. If you follow the link above, you'll see a lot of examples that don't have a conjunction at all.
In your example, the conjunction just has an important role to connect the two clauses and is, therefore, indispendsable.

Comment: I think one sufficient condition is that repeated words ("bestimmt"), at least verbs, can be always omitted.